# Are varieties determined by morphisms from curves?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, homological-algebra, schemes

For every scheme $X$, we can attach the functor $Hom(-,X): Sch \to Set $ and then Yoneda Lemma tells us $Hom(-,X)\cong Hom(-,Y)$ if and only if $X\cong Y$.

Now suppose $\mathcal A$ denote the full subcategory of $Sch$ consisting of integral, Noetherian schemes of  dimension $1$. For a fixed algebraically closed field $k$, let $\mathcal B_k$ denote the full subcategory of $Sch_k$ (so the morphisms are morphism of Schemes commuting with the structure morphism of $k$) consisting of integral $k$-schemes of finite type of dimension $1$ and let $\mathcal C_k$ denote the full subcategory of $Sch_k$ consisting of separated, integral $k$-schemes of finite type of pure dimension $1$.

I have three related questions:

(1) If $X,Y$ are integral, Noetherian schemes of finite dimension such that as functors $\mathcal A \to Set$, we have an isomorphism of functors $Hom(-,X)\cong Hom(-,Y)$, then is it true that $X \cong Y$ ?

(2) If $X,Y$ are integral $k$-schemes of finite type  such that as functors $\mathcal B_k \to Set$, we have an isomorphism of functors $Hom(-,X)\cong Hom(-,Y)$, then is it true that $X \cong Y$ ?

(3) If $X,Y$ are integral, separated $k$-schemes of finite type  such that as functors $\mathcal C_k \to Set$, we have an isomorphism of functors $Hom(-,X)\cong Hom(-,Y)$, then is it true that $X \cong Y$ ? If this is not true in general, then what if we also assume $X,Y$ are both quasi-projective, or both affine, or both projective ?

Comment: The answer to all questions should be yes by (general) Yoneda lemma. Just apply the functor to $X$. The identity hom on $X$ gives an hom $f:X\to Y$, which is the desired isomorphism.

Comment: It is more interesting to know if the answer is still yes when the categories involved do not contain the objects you are interested. For example, if you consider the category of affine schemes...

Comment: The yoneda lemma doesn't apply here, $X$ and $Y$ need not be curves, and thus the functor $hom(__,X)$ won't be necessarily representable as a functor from the different curve categories.

Comment: I think the answer to (2) should be no, because general type varieties should not have many curves on them. I don't know the answer to part (1), for example because now we are allowed to use the local rings of our points at curves. This should allow us to determine the function field of the variety, so we are at least getting some information.